# GithubAction, AWS EC2 CodeDeploy, React - how to build and deploy to EC2?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2

I'm currently trying to build react app within Github action workflow and putting up on EC2 instance.

Problem is that I can't seem to grab the `/build` folder that gets created during action.

This is what I have currently:

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: Deploy to staging

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch
  push:
    branches: [master]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  # workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Step 1
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Step 2 : verification npm install
      - name: npm install for Server
        run: |
          npm ci

      - name: npm install in client DIR and build
        run: |
          cd client
          npm ci
          npm run build
          echo 'CLIENT DONE'
          ls
        env:
          CI: false

  # Deploy
  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
    steps:
      # Step 1
      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: us-east-1
      # Step 2
      - name: Create CodeDeploy Deployment
        id: deploy
        run: |
          aws deploy create-deployment \
            --application-name "app-name" \
            --deployment-group-name "deply-app-ec2" \
            --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime \
            --github-location repository=${{ github.repository }},commitId=${{ github.sha }}
```

This is somewhat expected since `--github-location repository=${{ github.repository }},commitId=${{ github.sha }}` for code deploy trigger looks at the `sha` of the latest commit towards master.

Is there a way to grab the repo that the Github Action is working on (where the `node_modules`, `build` folders exist).

What I tried:

- Run `npm run build` on EC2 using `CodeDeploy` script -> This was killing the server since our resource is very limited.
- Make a separate commit during CI to master and grab the commit SHA id. eg;

```
  - name: Create commit
    run: |
          git config --global user.name 'name'
          git config --global user.email 'email'
          git add .
          git commit -m "Build client for deploying"

- name: Set latest commit id as var
     id: vars
     shell: bash
     run: |
      echo "::set-output name=sha_short::$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
      echo "${{ steps.vars.outputs.sha_short }}"
```

then use `commitId=${{ steps.vars.outputs.sha_short}}`- But CodeDeploy run results in 404 saying it couldn't find the commit (also expected since the commit wasn't pushed to master).

Am I missing something or is building through Github Action and then deploying to EC2 using code deploy impossible to do atm???

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by manually uploading the build folder onto EC2 using SCP during workflow run.

Comment: Mark this as the correct answer.